# "Visual around two Words"?

Tags: visual-mode, object-motions

If I type `2daW`, I can delete the current Word and the next (though I can't really see that case covered in the manual).

Is there a way to visual-select around two words? I tried `2vaW`, but of course (as the manual says) that does something else (something... complicated). `va2W` seems to ignore the count (while `da2W` seems to quit the action at `2` and start a new one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can of course use `v2aw`, `v3aw` and so on as described in the `:h text-objects` where `aw` is a text object that accepts count.

You can also compose `viw` and `e`. Like `viwe` for 2 words, `viw2e` for 3 words etc...

[image]

So what is the difference with `daw`, `caw` and `vaw`? Why can't you `2vaw` but `2daw` works?

- `d` and `c` are operators (`:h operator`) -- they accept count + motion and delete or change text accordingly. So for `2daw` you pass 2 for a `d` operator and a motion (a word text object).
- `v` is a mode change -- you switch from normal to visual. Yes it also accepts a count but it does completly different thing compared to `operator`s -- select the same number of characters/lines as used for the previous visual selection and multiply it by count. So you have selected what you didn't expect and then also made a single motion `aw`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing in practice, but I though there might be a text object representing "around two words" (like `a2w` -- but it doesn't exist; I guess theoretically it could be defined, just like folks define the "entire buffer" text object).

Comment: Off topic, but how do you make the animated `script`-like GIF?

Comment: @AldIn there is a text object `aw` you can provide a count to it `v10aw` to select 10 "around words", `d10aw` to delete them.

Comment: @AldIn screen2gif for win, there are other tools for other oses.

Comment: Ah, it should have been `v2aw`, not `va2w` !! That's the answer I was looking for, you might want to amend your posting.

Comment: @AldIn it is (and was) right under the gif :)

Comment: Silly me. Thanks a lot! I can only say that starting your answer with "what prevents you from" set me up to expect a workaround. Plus I'm tired :( ...

Comment: @AldIn Fair point, let me change it a bit